# Implement groupBox look in WinRT

Tags: windows-runtime

How can I implement a custom control which has the groupbox look, with a piece of text slightly overlapping the outside border and text contained inside?

Comment: What have you tried? It would seem like a grid with a rectangle could work. Also -- for a WinRT app, it's not typically needed. Are you sure it's the best UI choice?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still very new to WinRT and trying to find places to start.  I considered using a grid but I'm not sure how I could use that to get a label to overlap the border.

You're right that it may seem a bit out of place in a WinRT app but I'm looking at a mock up of it right now and it doesn't look bad.  At the very least I'd like to know how to make it so that I could implement it, try it out, and then decide if its a good idea or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a case of design integration, then your best bet might be to create a `ContentControl`-derived control with a template that has a root `Grid` with a `Border` element, a `TextBlock` for the label overlapping the `Border` and a `ContentPresenter` inside of the `Border`. Check the default `Button` template for inspiration since it might be quite similar.